# Impossible to build project with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

It is the first time i try to build a project with Maven, and it just doesn't work... I have no idea what to do.

Here are my specs:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache\maven
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stormpath.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>stormpath-spring-boot-spring-security-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <name>Spring Boot Spring Security Stormpath Tutorial</name>
    <description>A simple Spring Boot Web MVC application with Spring Security and out-of-the-box login and self-service screens!</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stormpath.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I run the command: "mvn clean install -e"
and I end up getting this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project stormpath-spring-boot-spring-security-tutorial: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project stormpath-spring-boot-spring-security-tutorial: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find main class
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.buildManifest(Repackager.java:291)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:207)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:152)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.repackage(RepackageMojo.java:206)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.execute(RepackageMojo.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
```

Comment: Do you have a main class in your application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot can detect your main class when you only have one. You probably have more than one, so Spring Boot can't know which one to use!

Since you are not using spring-boot as parent project, you need to specify the main class in `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.package.MainClass</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you were declaring spring-boot-starter-parent as your parent project, you could have just delcared the `start-class` property:

```
<start-class>com.package.MainClass</start-class>
```

Comment: I think this is not mandatory. The spring boot maven plugin will automatically scan for the `main()` method if the main class is not provided via configuration or via the manifest file. Check this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html). I suspect he does not have a main class.

Comment: I updated the answer (the first line) on this!